# How to write data in specified format into a binary file with Perl?

Tags: perl, file-io, binary, hex

this might be quite a newbie question, but i need to process a certain text file and dump its content into a binary file and i do not know how - i decided to use perl, but my perl skills are quite low. I probably should have written this in C++, but this seem like a nice and easy task for perl, so why not learn something new? ;) The text file has thousands of lines in this format:

`2A02FC42 4`

You can look at it as a hexadecimal number (the length is **ALWAYS** 8) and a regular number. Now i need to dump all the lines into a binary file in this format (it should look like this when viewed with a hex editor):

`42FC022A00000004`

More examples so it is clear:

`70726F67 36` ->  `676F727000000024` 
`6A656374 471` ->  `7463656A000001D7`

The part of parsing the input file is easy, but i'm stuck on the second part, where i should write this into a binary file. I have no idea how to format the data in this way or even how to output things in binary mode. Can someone help me out here?

Thanks.

EDIT: updated the examples, forgot about endiannes - im on a LE system.

Comment: http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/pack.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`pack`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/pack.html):

```
#! /usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;

# demo only    
*ARGV = *DATA;

while (<>) {
  my($a,$b) = split;
  $a = join "", reverse $a =~ /(..)/g;
  $b = sprintf "%08x", $b;

  print pack "H*" => $a . $b;
}

__DATA__
2A02FC42 4
70726F67 36
6A656374 471
```

Sample run:

```
$ ./prog.pl | od -t x1
0000000 42 fc 02 2a 00 00 00 04 67 6f 72 70 00 00 00 24
0000020 74 63 65 6a 00 00 01 d7
0000030
```

Comment: Note for the best portability, you should toggle binary mode for the output stream: `binmode(STD0UT)`

Answer (score 1):

My version (tested):

```
my $fout;
if ( ! open( $fout, ">/tmp/deleteme.bin" ) ) {
    die( "Failed to open /tmp/deleteme.bin: $!" );
}
binmode( $fout );

while ( <DATA> ) {
    my ( $left, $right ) = split( /\s+/s, $_ );

    my $output = pack( "VN", hex($left), int($right) );
    printf(
        STDERR
        "  note, %8X %d -> " . ( "%02X" x 8 ) . "\n",
        hex($left), $right,
        map { $_ } unpack( "C8", $output )
    );

    print( $fout $output );
}
close( $fout );

__DATA__
70726F67 36 -> 676F727000000024
6A656374 471 -> 7463656A000001D7
```

outputs:

```
note, 70726F67 36 -> 676F727000000024
note, 6A656374 471 -> 7463656A000001D7
```

Answer (score 0):

The canonical way is to use `pack`.  Let's suppose that the data you have read from the text file is already converted into numbers (including the hex one), and is stored in vars `$x` and `$y`.  Then you should do something like

```
 print OUTFILE pack("NN", $x, $y);
```

If you require different byteorder, you will have to use
different template from `NN`, see `perldoc -f pack` for details.